# Is there any need of encoding for the keys in application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, config

I need to have a compound name as a key in my application.yml. For example:

citrus:
fruits & vegetables: something

And I need to know if it needs any specific encoding or it will work by simply 'fruits & vegetables' or I need to escaped the & because fruits & vegetables does not work.

I found the solution, you must see what spring boot version you use for me it worked to use "[fruits & vegetables]"

Comment: Just a design advice (if possible in your case): use keys without special chars, maybe something like `fruits-and-vegetables`. And although string literals may be better supported in yml than in properties, often it's better to enquote them as well.

Comment: @Slevin i know this, but unfortunately i need this exact naming conventions so i was looking around to know if there is any encoding for application.yml files or any conventions

Answer (score 1):

I've done some research on this for you. There is a variety of solutions to your question.

You can quote the entier key, by enclosing it in single or double quotes:

`'citrus: fruits & vegetables': something'`

Or you can use square brackets, as you have said in your question:

`[citrus: fruits & vegetables]: something`

Using quotes is more common, and widely recognised. It ensures the entire string is treated as the key without any special processing of the characters within it.